# Decomposing Gaussian Diffraction Pattern

Tags: frequency-spectrum, gaussian, pattern

I was recommended to post this question here from the physics stack exchange. I have the following diffraction pattern produced by a fabry-perot etalon.
[image]

The red represents the center of that pattern. Taking the mean intensity of the pattern as a function of the radius from the red dot and applying a cut-off radius results in
[image]

This clearly shows a superposition of at least two diffraction patterns. Is there any way to automatically decompose the patterns? I originally tried Fourier analysis but that resulted in a complete mess as the peaks appear to be Gaussians, not sine functions. I can fit Gaussian to all the individual peaks. But then my question is if there is an algorithm or method that would allow me to determine which Gaussian belongs to which diffraction pattern. I have quite a few more diffraction patterns some of which are more complicated and I wanted to see if there is a way to automate this.